# Javascript:: Convert JSON string post callback to pure javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

I wrote a PHP function to check for array duplicates.

If the array have no duplicates it returned the array as a JSON string otherwise it print (as pure text) the duplicate(/d) value(/s).

My PHP function working perfectly.

Now what I want to do is to CONVERT that returned JSON string and use it as pure javascript array (off-course assuming that there is NO duplicates).

Here is my **hezi.php** file:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST')
{

    $gangina=array
    (
        'douplicateTesting',
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        'douplicateTesting',
        '4',
        '3'
    );

    function dupValidator()
    {

        global $gangina;

        if(count($gangina)===count(array_unique($gangina)))
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($gangina);
        }
        else
        {
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            echo'Opps! This array contains duplicates'."\r\n".str_repeat(chr(45),36)."\r\n\r\n";
            print_r(array_diff_key($gangina,array_unique($gangina)));
            exit;
        }

    }

    dupValidator();

}
```

This is my **index.htm** file (without the javascript ajax post callback):

```
<pre id=myStringify></pre>

<script>

var callbackArray=
[
    {
        value:1,
        type:wavFile
    }
    ,
    {
        value:2,
        type:aiffFile
    }
];

document.getElementById('myStringify').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(callbackArray,null,4);

</script>
```

In my `index.htm` wrote the a dummy JavaScript array just as a prototype so it would be easier to get the idea what I'm about to achieve here.

So this pure JavaScript array :

`var callbackArray=[{value:1,type:wavFile},{value:2,type:aiffFile}];`

Would be created via post AJAX callback request:

```
var callbackArray=<!--post AJAX callback request-->
```

I know how to do it via jQuery but I want to do it with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JavaScript function [JSON.parse(testString)](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp).  The documentation also mentions eval() for use with older browsers but as noted, you shouldn't use it if possible to prevent potential security problems.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d7c6030/1/).

Comment: I solved my problem in different way which was include major change on my code. This not what I was after bro.